# Dependency Problems Angular.js ngRoute ngSanitize

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey I am working on a Angular page and as soon as I tried to accept data through the URL like this

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
   $routeProvider.
   when('/watch/:videoID', { // <-- Like this
      templateUrl: 'partials/watchSingle',
      controller: 'watchSingle'
   }).
   when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/index',
      controller: 'mainPage'
   }).
   otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
   });
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

JS started throwing this error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: $routeProviderProvider <- $routeProvider
```

I searched the error and Stackoverflow told me to add ngRoute and ngSanitize as a Dependency. After adding that I got three new errors:

```
Error: Unknown provider: $sceProvider <- $sce <- $route <- ngViewDirective
Error: Circular dependency: ngViewDirective
Error: Circular dependency: ngViewDirective
```

I have the feeling that I am missing some more dependencies but I can not figure out which ones.

Info: ngRoute and ngSanitize are the only dependencies I have included.

Comment: Are you sure that you use angularjs and angularjs-route as compatible versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

//code
```

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    })

change your config with above.
and remove `#` from the eg :`<a href="/watch"></a>` in html view